# Google Calendar Resource: How to get calendar ID from event instance?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

If you list Google Calendar events using [this API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) or particular event using  [this API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) specifying Calendar Resource room ID instead of calendar ID, you get list of all events associated to that Calendar Resource.

If you then want to delete or modify that event using domain-wide delegation of authority you can get event owner form `creator.email` field.

The question is how to get calendar ID where the event is created to be able to delete or modify it?

Of course you can try to use creator's e-mail or `primary` for the calendar ID but this fails if the user created the event in any other than default calendar.

Comment: Thank you for the link! I was trying to find some Google Calendar Google Group, which is currently abandoned, or support form where to could put this question but without success.

Comment: If you like, you may star a feature request with this https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5092&thanks=5092&ts=1485601774

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me but let's try. If you use the list or the get call, that already requires you to specify the calendar ID and so all the events you get from them reside on that calendar and you can modify them using the same calendar ID (only respond if you are an attendee). If you want to know where the main copy of the event lives, the field is called "organizer". Check this out: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing

Comment: But you can specify Calendar Resource ID instead of Calendar ID (see https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/ about what Calendar Resources are) to list its events. Then you do not have the actual calendar ID because organizer fields contains only ID of the user that created the event, but not ID of their calendars where the event is created.